# How to Downgrade my Huawei U8815 from Android 4.0.3 to 2.3.6?

Tags: huawei, downgrade

One month ago I bought my phone Huawei U8815 Ascend G300 with Android version 2.3.6 and it was running fine.

Recently I upgraded my Android to version 4.0.3 , but unfortunately the system became too slow, and the battery becomes empty within two hours. While it ran the whole day when I had Android 2.3.6. Because of that I would like to install my old android 2.3.6, if you can kindly help me the right way to do so, please.

### Remarks about my system: Huawei u8815 information

Model number: HUWAWEI U8815
Android version: 4.0.3
Baseband version: 2030
Kernel version: 3.0.8-perf-00242-gcb0aa96 android@localhost#1
Build number : U8815V100R001C00B939

Comment: Before downgrading, two things you might want to check: in the battery stats, see what's eating all the battery (which is probably the same app making your phone slow). Second, a factory-reset might also prove helpful if things got messed up during the update.